Visualization of Minimization Problem
I am trying to visualize the objective function (f1), the constraint (isoq), and the optimal solution. The optimal solution is at the tangency of both graphs. I can plot the constraint, but the objective function with optimal values does not illustrate tangency, and there is an error message of "Inverse functions being used by Solve...".
```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*Define the cost function-objective*)
cost[l_, k_, w_, r_] := w*l + r*k;
(*Define the isocost function-illustration*)
isoc[w_, r_, c_] := k /. Solve[cost[l, k, w, r] == c, k][[1]]
(*Define the general Cobb-Douglas production function-constraint*)
f1[l_, k_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := k^\[Alpha]*l^\[Beta]
(*Define the isoquant function-illustration*)
isoq[q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := k /. Solve[f1[l, k, \[Alpha], \[Beta]] == q, k]
(*Define the solution for the minimization problem*)
lstarvalue1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))*(\[Beta]   r (\[Alpha]   w))^((1 - \[Alpha])/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
kstarvalue1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))*(\[Beta]   r/(\[Alpha]   w))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
(*Define the optimal point and corresponding isocost line*)
opt1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := Evaluate[{lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}]
f1s[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := Quiet[k /.Solve[cost[## & @@ opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], w, r] == cost[l, k, w, r], k][[1]]];
(*Highlighting tangent point*) 
hstarline1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := Line[{{0,kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, {lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha],\[Beta]]}}]
vstarline1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := Line[{{lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 0}, {lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}}]
(*Illustrate isocost,isoquant,and tangent point with sliders of exogenous values*)
Manipulate[
Plot[{isoq[q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], f1s[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, 
{l, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> {0, 10000},
Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, hstarline1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], vstarline1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], PointSize@Large, Point@opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]],Text["Optimal Bundle", opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], {-1, -2}]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"Labor", "Capital"}, 
PlotLabel -> "Optimal Choice: Labor vs. Capital", 
ImageSize -> {500, 300}], 
{{w, 5}, 0, 30, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{r, 10}, .01, 30, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{q, 2500}, 0, 5000, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{\[Alpha], 0.5}, 0, 1, .05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{\[Beta], 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Button["Reset", {w = 5, r = 10, q = 2500, \[Alpha] = 0.5, \[Beta] = 0.5}],
ContentSize -> {550, 350}]
```

Thank you!


The problem is that $x=y^\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is a solotion to the equation $x^\alpha=y$, but not the only solution. $x=y^\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{2k\pi}{a}}$ is also a solution to the equation, where k is any integer. This is why Mathematica says "so some solutions may not be found".
You can add assumptions to make the solution unique.
Solve[k^\[Alpha]*l^\[Beta] == q, k, 
 Assumptions -> {q > 0, k > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, l^\[Beta] > 0}]

or just turn off the annoying message at the beginning.
Off[Solve::ifun]

Of course, for such a simple function, it may be more convenient to solve it manually.
isoq[q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := (l^-\[Beta] q)^(1/\[Alpha])

Below is the complete code.
Clear["Global`*"]
(*Off[Solve::ifun]*)
(*Define the cost function-objective*)
cost[l_, k_, w_, r_] := w*l + r*k;
(*Define the isocost function-illustration*)
isoc[w_, r_, c_] := Evaluate[k /. Solve[cost[l, k, w, r] == c, k][[1]]]
(*Define the general Cobb-Douglas production function-constraint*)
f1[l_, k_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := k^\[Alpha]*l^\[Beta]
(*Define the isoquant function-illustration*)
isoq[q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Evaluate[
  k /. Solve[f1[l, k, \[Alpha], \[Beta]] == q, k, 
     Assumptions -> {q > 0, k > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, 
       l^\[Beta] > 0}][[1]]]
(*Define the solution for the minimization problem*)
lstarvalue1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))*(\[Beta]    r  (\[Alpha]    w))^((1 - \
\[Alpha])/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
kstarvalue1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))*(\[Beta]    r/(\[Alpha]    w))^(\[Beta]/(\
\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
(*Define the optimal point and corresponding isocost line*)
opt1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Evaluate[{lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
   kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}]
f1s[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
  Evaluate[
   k /. Solve[
      cost[## & @@ opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], w, r] == 
       cost[l, k, w, r], k][[1]]];
(*Highlighting tangent point*)
hstarline1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Line[{{0, 
    kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, {lstarvalue1[w, r, 
     q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
    kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}}]
vstarline1[w_, r_, q_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 Line[{{lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
    0}, {lstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
    kstarvalue1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}}]
(*Illustrate isocost,isoquant,and tangent point with sliders of \
exogenous values*)
Manipulate[
 Plot[{isoq[q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
   f1s[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, {l, 0, 10000}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 10000}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, hstarline1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
    vstarline1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], PointSize@Large, 
    Point@opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], 
    Text["Optimal Bundle", 
     opt1[w, r, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta]], {-1, -2}]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Labor", "Capital"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Optimal Choice: Labor vs. Capital", 
  ImageSize -> {500, 300}], {{w, 5}, 0, 30, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 10}, .01, 30, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{q, 2500}, 0, 5000, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 0.5}, 0, 1, .05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Beta], 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Reset", {w = 5, r = 10, 
   q = 2500, \[Alpha] = 0.5, \[Beta] = 0.5}], 
 ContentSize -> {550, 350}]

Second Edit:
It seems that there is something wrong with your solution (of course, it may also be that I still don't understand your problem correctly).
I guess your problem is to find the minimum value of $\mathrm{cost}(k,l)$ under the constraint $f_1(k,l)=q$.
I solved it manually by myself using the Lagrange multiplier method. Here are my results:
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{k^\[Alpha]*l^\[Beta] == q, 
   w*l + r*k == 
    q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
        w  ((r \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta])) + 
     q^(1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))
        r  ((r \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta])))}, {l, 0, 
   10000}, {k, 0, 10000}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
    Line[{{0, q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))}, {q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))), q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))}}], 
    Line[{{q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))), 0}, {q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))), q^(
       1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
        w \[Alpha]))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))}}], 
    PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{q^(
      1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))), q^(
      1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))}], 
    Text["Optimal Bundle", {q^(
      1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(-(\[Alpha]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))), q^(
      1/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))/((r  \[Beta])/(
       w \[Alpha]))^(\[Beta]/(\[Alpha] + \[Beta]))}, {-1, -2}]},
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Labor", "Capital"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Optimal Choice: Labor vs. Capital"], {{w, 5}, 0, 30, 
  0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 10}, .01, 30, 0.5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{q, 2500}, 0, 5000, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Alpha], 0.5}, 0, 1, .05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Beta], 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Reset", {w = 5, r = 10, 
   q = 2500, \[Alpha] = 0.5, \[Beta] = 0.5}], 
 ContentSize -> {550, 350}]



Thank you! The error message is gone but the output is not correct. I added a picture showing the lack of tangency.

@Tom In fact, I don't know which part of your code is used to draw the tangent line, nor do I know what effect you want to achieve.

The orange line is the objective function f1s, and the blue one is the constraint isoq. At the optimal point the blue and orange curves should be tangent - tangency condition of a minimum.

@Tom Maybe you just miscalculated.
